# Libgdx label text not inside label bounds

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to create a table and put in a label in the table in libgdx. I put the debug lines in and I can see that the label text is not contained within the label box.

This is my code where i setup my table and add it to the stage. If any other code might be needed just say in the comments, or suggest any problems I might have overlooked.

```
private void setupTable (){

     table = new Table();
     table.setWidth(Constants.APP_WIDTH);
     table.setHeight(Constants.APP_HEIGHT);
     table.align(Align.center);
     table.setPosition(0f, 0f);
     table.debug();


     //create different labels
     Label.LabelStyle style = new LabelStyle(font, Color.WHITE);

     Label label = new Label("hi", style);
     label.setAlignment(Align.center);

     label.setFontScale(Constants.Font.HIGH_SCORE_SCALE);


     table.add(label);
     addActor(table);



}
```

This is what it looks like when I run the application on desktop with the debug lines:
[image]

To make sure it is nothing with the font I tried with two other fonts

Comment: Show your viewport setup and resizing. I'm thinking this might be fixed by calling `setUseIntegerPostions(false)` on your source BitmapFont.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I already called the setUseIntegerPositions (false) on the bitmap font in another function that I called. As for the viewport setup. All I did was use screenViewport, and then set the camera to my camera that i used throughout my whole game. If the code is needed I will add it.

Comment: Instead of setting a position, width, and height on the table, try setting `setFillParent(true)` on it. Table is not intended to be sized directly, so that might be part of the problem.